# select2 formatState not work with bootstrap 4 theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I add Bootstrap 4 theme using [select2 bootstrap theme](https://github.com/ttskch/select2-bootstrap4-theme) to select2 and need to add `<span></span>` to text using `formatState` method.

My HTML code is:

```
<div class="fieldset fieldset-1">
   <label for="color">Choose color</label>
   <select name="color" class="select2">                             
      <option value="grn">Green</option>
      <option value="blu">Blue</option>
      <option value="brn">Brown</option>
      <option value="blk">Black</option>
      <option value="red">Red</option>
      <option value="yel">Yellow</option>
      <option value="wht">White</option>                                  
    </select>
 </div>
```

And Js:

```
    function formatState (state) {
        if (!state.id) {
            return state.text;
        }
        var baseUrl = "/user/pages/images/flags";
        var $state = $(
            '<span><img src="' + baseUrl + '/' + state.element.value.toLowerCase() + '.png" class="img-flag" /> ' + state.text + '</span>'
        );
        return $state;
    };

    $(".select2").select2({
        templateResult: formatState
    });

    $('select').select2({
        theme: 'bootstrap4',
    });
```

In action select2 not show `<span></span>`. i check my Js Code and remove this line(bootstrap 4 theme):

```
$('select').select2({
    theme: 'bootstrap4',
});
```

now select2 work and I see `<span></span>`. How do can I fix this problem?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following in JS

```
    function formatState (state) {
    if (!state.id) {
        return state.text;
    }
    var baseUrl = "/user/pages/images/flags";
    var $state = $(
        '<span><img src="' + baseUrl + '/' + state.element.value.toLowerCase() + 
      '.png" class="img-flag" /> ' + state.text + '</span>'
    );
    return $state;
  };

   $(".select2").select2({
      theme: 'bootstrap4',
      templateResult: formatState
   });
```